# How to create multi layout in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I know about Apache Tiles in Spring, it seem working same jsp:include, but it doesn't solve my problem:
I want a file with name is layout1.jsp, in this file, I will define a layout like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style href="style1.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>${message }</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <span>This is footer</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a file is layout2.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<style href="style2.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="left2">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content2">
            <h1>${message }</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="footer2">
            <span>This is footer</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When user chose layout name on combobox, controller will set layout dynamic before render layout.

How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a method to solve this problem:

My application separator to multi module, example "Admin", "Default", each module have a interceptor, example a module interceptor:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
        if (!servletPath.equals("/") && servletPath.substring(servletPath.length() - 1).equals("/")) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + servletPath.replaceAll("\\/+$", ""));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In view I have a class InternalResourceViewResolver.java:

```
package view;

import helper.AppHelper;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

public class InternalResourceViewResolver extends
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver {

    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale)
            throws Exception {
        AppHelper.setPage("../" + AppHelper.getModule() + "/" + viewName + ".jsp");
        return super.resolveViewName("layout/" + AppHelper.getLayout(), locale);
    }

}
```

AppHelper class:

```
package helper;

public class AppHelper {
    private static String module = "default";
    private static String layout = "main";
    private static String page = "index";

    public static String getModule() {
        return module;
    }
    public static void setModule(String module) {
        AppHelper.module = module;
    }
    public static String getLayout() {
        return layout;
    }
    public static void setLayout(String layout) {
        AppHelper.layout = layout;
    }
    public static String getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public static void setPage(String page) {
        AppHelper.page = page;
    }
}
```

In other module, example for Admin:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ServletPath" + request.getServletPath());
        AppHelper.setModule("admin");
        AppHelper.setLayout("admin");
        return true;
    }
```

And my view page:

In layout:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Welcome to web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-left">
                    <jsp:include page="<%=helper.AppHelper.getPage() %>"></jsp:include>
                </div>
                <div class="content-right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Placeholder page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<h1>${message }</h1>
<h2>${welcome }</h2>
<c:forEach items="${batches }" var="batch">  
    ${batch.id } - ${batch.name }
</c:forEach>
```

Here directory struct:

```
- src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages
    - admin
        - index
            - index.jsp
            - setting.jsp
        - product
            - index.jsp
            - detail.jsp
        - other
            ...
    - default
        - index
            - index.jsp
            - contact.jsp
        - product
            ...
    - layout
        admin.jsp
        main.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

For switching the css file an you could use the Spring Theme Resolver. And you can use the same mechanism to change some small parts of your html (like the `div` classes)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
   <head>
       <style href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" />          
   </head>
   <body>
       ...
       <div class="<spring:theme code='contentClass'/>">
           <h1>${message }</h1>
       </div>
       ...
   </body>
</html>
```

(*But I would recommend to use the same html with same classes and just switch the css*).

Do not forget to setup the theme resolver!

@See [Spring Reference: Chapter Using themes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Tiles too ...

use apache-tiles 2.2.1 or above

In application's tiles.xml where you put layout models do this

```
<definition name="masterTile" templateExpression="${requestScope.layout} >
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/view/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/view/menu"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/view/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

For more on this refer here [Tiles Expression Language Support](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/el-support.html)